# modify existing paths for Raphael?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, svg, raphael, coordinates

I have a JS object that Raphael uses to generate a clickable SVG map. I need to modify some of the paths. Is there a tool I can use to do that in a **user-friendly** manner? I don't want to fiddle with numbers using trial-and-error technique, I want to drag and drop paths/anchor points. Can I somehow import the coordinates into Illustrator/Dreamweaver/any other tool?

Thank you.

Here's what the JS object looks like:

```
map.coords   = [
{ type:"path" ,id:"K15" ,d:"/*edited out*/"},
{ type:"rect" ,id:"K14" ,x:"496" ,y:"386" ,width:"9" ,height:"5"}
];
```

Here's what the markup looks like (with Raphael-generated markup inside the `svg` element):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div id="mapOverlay" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2">
    <svg height="777" width="777" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <desc>Created with Raphaël</desc>
        <defs></defs>
        <path fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="0.25" style="stroke-width: 0.25; fill-opacity: 0;" d="[/*edited out*/]" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"></path>
    </svg>
    </div>
<img src="map.jpg" alt="Interactive Map">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you simply looking for a good tool to manipulate paths?  Have you taken a gander at SVG-edit?  http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html  You can manipulate paths in the manner you describe and yet easily retrieve or work with the raw SVG markup.  I have learned to love it!

Comment: @KevinNielsen: Looks good. How would I go about it? Need to grab the <svg></svg>, save it as well-formed SVG and import it into SVG-edit? Can I superimpose an image on top of it (I have one for reference on what to update)?

Comment: Hey @dalbaeb, I usually use this approach.  Create the svg and create a simple path, then switch to svg view, copy your path string over the d attribute of the path you've created, switch back to the editor and make my changes/additions, then snag the modified d attribute. So the only thing I'm really moving in/out of the editor is the path string.  It's not perfect -- but it is effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Kevin Nielsen's comment to the question is a perfectly doable approach, while waiting I figured out how to do it in Illustrator. Here's how:

1. yank out the entire contents of `<svg>` tag and save it as a separate file
2. add this to the beginning of your file:

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
3. In Illustrator File -> Open. If it doesn't open you can run it through the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to see what is wrong with it. Make sure you specify SVG 1.1 as Document Type in the settings.
4. You can then superimpose any image (it's best if it's the same dimensions) by using File -> Place command in Illustrator.

Comment: I can rock and roll with that (though I do try to avoid Illustrator whenever I can)!

Comment: @KevinNielsen Why? Because it's proprietary?

Comment: Not so much because it's proprietary -- more because it's slow to load and I'm a curmudgeon =)